# MVC Vanity URL Routing?

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using .NET MVC 5 and I cannot get vanity URL routing working and have yet to find an example on line that works. RouteMagic doesn't do it, though some claim it does. Our site is multi-tenant. Here's an example:

Say our site is www.example.com and when an organization registers they pick their vanity url and then their site is www.example.com/OurOrganization. I have yet to find a single example of this working in C# MVC and it kind of surprises me.

Thus, I have even hard coded it like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "OurOrganization",
    "OurOrganization/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

It kind of works, but when hit the normal standard route without "OurOrganization" when I hover over the menu it shows the links as "OurOrganization" . If I add "AnotherOrganization" undermeath "OurOrganization" in the route table it will work but always defaults to OurOrganization on the menu.

For instance, I'm sitting on

http://www.example.com/AnotherOrganization

and click on "About" in the menu and it goes to

http://www.example.com/OurOrganization/Home/About  ??

I know this isn't the right way to do it, it should be an easy thing to do. I use MeetUp and host our Jeep club up there, they do exactly that, you pick your url and they tack it on the end of Meetup dot com, beautiful. Meetup must not be using .NET as I have yet to find an example of this in C#, 3 days into it and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to use something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "OurOrganization",
    "{organizationvanity}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { organizationvanity = "OurOrganization", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Or you could use attribute routing:

And decorate the Controller with

```
[RoutePrefix("{client}/case")]
```

Comment: I only wish it was that easy! I think stackoverflow is written in C# and I see that this post itself has what is essentially a vanity url. Unfortunately what I need to do is beyond what routes can do. I have a sample that is for multi-lingual MVC apps that involves deriving from MvcRouteHandler and another class that implements IRouteConstraint and more, not for the faint of heart. But does allow you to have say 

http://www.example.com/en/Home (english)

and 

http://www.example.com/fr/Home (french)

and so on, so that's basically the same thing, but really complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is 2 months old, but lacks an accepted answer...so I hope this helps.

This is a really good article on Attribute Routing (i.e. Vanity URLs):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Easiest thing in a nutshell is to add this to the RouteConfig within RegisterRoutes:

```
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()
```

And then add attributes to your controllers for the URL you want.

For example...I added "<'Route("{action}")'>" (without the single quotes) as an attribute to one of my controllers, so the URL for any of the actions in that controller will be that of the index page then /[action], instead of /[controller]/[action].